# Global dimension of the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring.

Must the global dimension of the centre $Z(R)$ of the ring $R$ always be atmost that of $R$ itself?
I mean is it generally true that: $D(Z(R)) \leq  D(R)$ (where D is the global dimension)?

Comment: An excellent name for an online business. hmmm; just checked, usually it is Global Center For something. Oh, well.

Comment: lol ok i gave it a better title (but i do agree haha)

Comment: What about $R=Z(R)$? Or do you mean $\leq$ instead of "smaller"?

Comment: Sorry, i clarified that now; thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the path algebra over a field $k$ of the quiver
$$\begin{array}{ccc} & \alpha & \\ \bullet & \rightleftarrows & \bullet \\ & \beta & \end{array}$$
subject to the relation
$$\beta\alpha=0.$$

So $R$ is $5$-dimensional, with basis $\{e_1,e_2,\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta\}$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are idempotents with $e_1+e_2=1$ and $e_1e_2=0=e_2e_1$, and where $e_1\alpha=\alpha=\alpha e_2$ and $e_2\beta=\beta=\beta e_1$.

Then the global dimension of $R$ is $2$, but the centre of $R$, which is spanned by $1$ and $\alpha\beta$, has infinite global dimension.